# Generate new bearer token with simple_oauth programmatically?

Tags: 8, authentication-authorization

I have a custom service and in the custom service, I want to generate a new Bearer token for the current user ( it's logged in) with simple_oauth module. in its documentation is has not mentioned how can I generate new a new token for current logged in user. **So, how can I generate a new Bearer token for current logged in user?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you need an access token for some API call, so to have it generated automatically when you call some API method in your service.

I usually go with the following set up:

1. Install kamermans/guzzle-oauth2-subscriber with composer
2. Define config `my_module.auth.yml` and import it

```
client_id: test
client_secret: test
base_uri: 'https://some-external-service/auth/token'
```

3. Create the following services/factories `my_module.services.yml`

```
services:
  my_module.handler_stack:
    class: GuzzleHttp\HandlerStack
    factory: ['GuzzleHttp\HandlerStack', 'create']
    calls:
      - [push, ['@my_module.oauth2_middleware']]

  my_module.client_factory:
    class: Drupal\my_module\Client\ClientFactory
    arguments: ['@config.factory']
   
  my_module.oauth2_middleware_factory:
    class: Drupal\my_module\Auth\OAuth2MiddlewareFactory
    arguments: ['@config.factory']

  my_module.oauth2_middleware.client:
    class: GuzzleHttp\Client
    factory: 'my_module.client_factory:createClient'
    arguments:
      - 'my_module.auth'

  my_module.oauth2_middleware:
    class: kamermans\OAuth2\OAuth2Middleware
    factory: 'my_module.oauth2_middleware_factory:createMiddleware'
    arguments:
      - '@my_module.oauth2_middleware.client'
      - 'my_module.auth'
```

4. Define your middleware factory `OAuth2MiddlewareFactory.php`

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\my_module\Auth;

use Drupal\Core\Config\ConfigFactoryInterface;
use GuzzleHttp\ClientInterface;
use kamermans\OAuth2\GrantType\ClientCredentials;
use kamermans\OAuth2\OAuth2Middleware;

/**
 * Factory for OAuth2 Guzzle middleware, configured from configuration objects.
 *
 * @package Drupal\my_module\Auth
 */
class OAuth2MiddlewareFactory {
  
  /**
   * The configuration factory.
   *
   * @var \Drupal\Core\Config\ConfigFactoryInterface
   */
  private $configFactory;

  /**
   * OAuth2MiddlewareFactory constructor.
   *
   * @param \Drupal\Core\Config\ConfigFactoryInterface $configFactory
   *   The configuration factory to use.
   */
  public function __construct(ConfigFactoryInterface $configFactory) {
    $this->configFactory = $configFactory;
  }

  /**
   * Creates an OAuth2 Guzzle Middleware.
   *
   * @param \GuzzleHttp\ClientInterface $client
   *   The guzzle HTTP client to use for obtaining client credentials.
   * @param string $configName
   *   Name of the configuration object to use.
   *
   * @return \kamermans\OAuth2\OAuth2Middleware
   *   The Guzzle Oauth2 middleware.
   */
  public function createMiddleware(ClientInterface $client, string $configName): OAuth2Middleware {
    $configuration = $this->configFactory->get($configName);

    $reauth_config = [
      'client_id' => $configuration->get('client_id'),
      'client_secret' => $configuration->get('client_secret'),
      'state' => time(),
    ];

    if ($configuration->get('scope')) {
      $reauth_config['scope'] = $configuration->get('scope');
    }

    $grant_type = new ClientCredentials($client, $reauth_config);

    return new OAuth2Middleware($grant_type);
  }

}
```

5. Define client factory `ClientFactory.php`

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\my_module\Client;

use Drupal\Core\Config\ConfigFactoryInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Config\ImmutableConfig;
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use GuzzleHttp\RequestOptions;

/**
 * Factory for Guzzle HTTP clients, configured from configuration objects.
 *
 * @package Drupal\my_module\Client
 */
class ClientFactory {
  
  /**
   * The configuration object factory.
   *
   * @var \Drupal\Core\Config\ConfigFactoryInterface
   */
  protected $configFactory;

  /**
   * ClientFactory constructor.
   *
   * @param \Drupal\Core\Config\ConfigFactoryInterface $configFactory
   *   The configuration object factory.
   */
  public function __construct(ConfigFactoryInterface $configFactory) {
    $this->configFactory = $configFactory;
  }

  /**
   * Creates a Guzzle HTTP client.
   *
   * @param string $configName
   *   Name of the configuration object to use.
   * @param array $clientConfig
   *   Additional configuration settings for the Guzzle HTTP client.
   *
   * @return \GuzzleHttp\Client
   *   A configured Guzzle HTTP client.
   */
  public function createClient(string $configName, array $clientConfig = []): Client {
    $config = $this->configFactory->get($configName);

    $prepared_config = $this->prepareClientConfig($config, $clientConfig);

    return new Client(
      $prepared_config
    );
  }

  /**
   * Prepares the configuration of the Guzzle HTTP client.
   *
   * Priority of the configuration:
   *   1. configuration in $config, limited to certain common settings
   *   2. configuration in $clientConfig passed in via the service container
   *   3. defaults set in this method.
   *
   * @param \Drupal\Core\Config\ImmutableConfig $config
   *   The configuration object to use.
   * @param array $clientConfig
   *   Additional configuration settings for the Guzzle HTTP client.
   *
   * @return array
   *   The client configuration.
   */
  protected function prepareClientConfig(ImmutableConfig $config, array $clientConfig = []): array {
    $prepared_config = $clientConfig;

    $prepared_config['base_uri'] = $config->get('base_uri');

    $defaults = [
      RequestOptions::TIMEOUT => $clientConfig[RequestOptions::TIMEOUT] ?? 10,
      RequestOptions::CONNECT_TIMEOUT => $clientConfig[RequestOptions::TIMEOUT] ?? 10,
    ];

    foreach (array_keys($defaults) as $option) {
      $prepared_config[$option] = $config->get($option) ?? $defaults[$option];
    }

    return $prepared_config;
  }

}
```

6. Define your client by using the factory in `my_module.services.yml`

```
  my_module.my_service.client:
    class: GuzzleHttp\Client
    factory: 'my_module.client_factory:createClient'
    arguments:
      - 'my_module.my_service'
      - auth: oauth
        handler: '@my_module.handler_stack'
```

where `my_module.my_service.yml` is

```
base_uri: 'https://some-external-service/a-service-namespace/'
```

7. Create your service that will trigger API by using the client you created by the factory earlier

```
  my_module.service.region:
    class: Drupal\my_module\Service\MyService
    arguments: ['@my_module.my_service.client']
```

and this is `MyService.php`

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\my_module\Service\Region;

use GuzzleHttp\ClientInterface;

/**
 * API client for my service.
 *
 * @package Drupal\my_module\Service
 */
class MyService {
  
  /**
   * A guzzle HTTP client.
   *
   * @var \GuzzleHttp\ClientInterface
   */
  private $client;

  /**
   * MyService constructor.
   *
   * @param \GuzzleHttp\ClientInterface $client
   *   A Guzzle HTTP client.
   */
  public function __construct(ClientInterface $client) {
    $this->client = $client;
  }

  /**
   * Finds something from the my service.
   *
   * @param string $langCode
   *   The language code.
   * @param string $postalCode
   *   The postal code.
   *
   * @throws \GuzzleHttp\Exception\GuzzleException
   */
  public function findSomething(string $langCode, string $value): Region {
    $response = $this->client->request('GET', 'my-service-uri/find',
      [
        'headers' => [
          'Accept' => 'application/json',
          'Accept-Language' => $langCode,
        ],
        'query' => [
          'value' => $value,
        ],
      ]
    );

    $json = $response->getBody()->getContents();

    // Do something here, you may use serializer to deserialize the content
    // here with the custom defined model or some other fancy stuff.

  }

}
```

This might too much, but you may find some useful code

Answer (score 0):

POST request to /oauth/token generates a new token (don't forget to add proper body params)

You can also use a refresh token to generate a new access token by using grant_type 'refresh_token'

Comment: thanks for you attention. yes, I knew this solution but I'm looking for a better solution. :)

Comment: additionally, the grant_type is password and  I don't have all users' passwords. so it's better to use another solution.

Comment: password grant type is now deprecated in the latest version of the module and is no longer available to generate tokens